# Read only specific part first two lines from text file in python

Tags: python

**Here's my problem description:-** i have a .txt file to be read and i want only specific part of the first two lines to be read and printed

here's the txt

```
NAME: "AAAAAA AAAAAA", DESCR: "bbbbbb bbbbbb, ccc. ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc "
PID: dd-ddddd-d        , VID: 23s  , SN: qqqqqqqqq              #Here

NAME: "ggggggggggg", DESCR: "hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh" 
PID: yy-yyyyy-yy-yy    , VID: Q23  , SN: ftyujnbghjn
```

The above text is as it is written in the text file ans i wan to read only 
**PID: dd-ddddd-d** and **SN: qqqqqqqq** from the second line (see #Here in txt) and ignore the rest.!

thx for the help.! :-)

Comment: they are two separate lines.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can read line by line and find the necessary data:

```
with open('yourTextFile.txt', "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if "PID" in line or "SN" in line:
            dataArr = line.split(",")
            for data in dataArr:
                if 'PID' in data:
                    print(data)
                if 'SN' in data:
                    print(data)
```

output:

```
PID: dd-ddddd-d        
 SN: qqqqqqqqq              

PID: yy-yyyyy-yy-yy    
 SN: ftyujnbghjn
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `readlines()`, it converts text file into lists.

Eg:

```
with open('demo.txt') as file:
    print(file.readlines()[1])   //fetches second line as I have used indexing here([1])
```

Expected output will be `PID: dd-ddddd-d        , VID: 23s  , SN: qqqqqqqqq`

I have used `with open()` because it automatically closes the file once it has been read.

To get the result:

```
with open('demo.txt') as file:
    second_line = file.readlines()[1]
    list_again = second_line.split(',')
```

Expected output: `['PID: dd-ddddd-d        ', ' VID: 23s  ', ' SN: qqqqqqqqq        \n']`

Now you can use `indexing` to retrieve specific values.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('file', 'r') as f:
    file_as_list = f.readlines()
for line in file_as_list:
    result = re.findall(r'PID:\s[a-z-]+|SN:\s[a-z-]+', line)
    if result:
        print(result)
```

output:

```
['PID: dd-ddddd-d', 'SN: qqqqqqqqq']
['PID: yy-yyyyy-yy-yy', 'SN: ftyujnbghjn']
```